# How Should I check if someone is in a certain location when Database Updates

Tags: node.js, react-native, performance, location, location-updates

I'm currently trying to build something similar to [Amber Alerts](https://amberalert.ojp.gov/about/faqs) where whenever a database table is updated, I check if users are in a certain area.

For example, let's say a user makes a report that they found a wallet at their current location. The database is updated where a new row is created with the latitude and longitude of that report location, and then I want to check which users are in a 5 mile radius of that lat-long.

I have every user's phone number but that's about it. I am successfully able to get the  location of the report (my frontend provides that in the request data to the backend) but I'm unsure on how to get the location of other users.

How would I do this?

I am using Node JS for my backend and React Native for my frontend.

Thanks!

Comment: How about Geofence?
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/#locationstartgeofencingasynctaskname-regions